# ng-repeat-start nested object within a table

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use a table to display the following information in the following format.

[image]

Here's a plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/iYEVqUOU3aS4y0t9L1Qa?p=preview

```
$scope.persons = [
    {
     "name":"Mandy",
     "homes":[
            {
                "location":"California",
                "size":"medium",
                "furniture":[
                    {
                        "name":"couch",
                        "color":"white"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"table",
                        "color":"black"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
      }
  ]
```

and the html

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>House</th>
    <th>Furniture</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
      <td>{{person.name}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat-start="home in person.homes">
        <ul>
          <li>{{home.location}}</li>
        </ul>  
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat-end>
         <ul ng-repeat="furniture in home.furniture">
          <li>{{furniture.name}}</li>
        </ul> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


</div>
```

This works great with 1 home and multiple furniture but I run into ui/table issues when there's more than 1 home (along with multiple furniture).

I've tried moving the ng-repeat-start to the ul element but angular complains about not being able to find an ng-repeat-end when I do this. So instead of repeat ul's I'm forced to repeat td which messes the ui up when there's more than 1 home.

I made another plnkr so you can see what it looks like with 2 homes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q37peH968SJc9OvD8lif?p=preview

Is there another way around this ng-repeat-start / end limitation?

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to display 3-dimensional data (person-home-furniture) in a 2-dimensional grid (the table). Before this problem can be solved, you need to describe (or draw out) what you'd like to see - then we can figure out how to achieve that result.

Comment: @Agop I updated the op with a picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, the problem is that you're trying to display 3-dimensional data (person-home-furniture) in a 2-dimensional grid (the table).

Without flattening your data, the solution is to use multiple table bodies as a third dimension:

1. table body = person
2. row = home
3. list within cell = furniture

See snippet below for an example. Note that we're giving the first column (the person's name) a `rowspan` equal to the number of homes, and we're only showing it for the person's first home.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('PersonHomeFurnitureCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.persons = [{
    "name": "Mandy",
    "height": 5,
    "homes": [{
      "location": "California",
      "size": "medium",
      "furniture": [{
        "name": "couch",
        "color": "white"
      }, {
        "name": "table",
        "color": "black"
      }]
    }, {
      "location": "Arizona",
      "size": "large",
      "furniture": [{
        "name": "couch",
        "color": "blue"
      }, {
        "name": "table",
        "color": "light brown"
      }]
    }]
  }]

});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="PersonHomeFurnitureCtrl">

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>House</th>
      <th>Furniture</th>
    </thead>
    <!-- one table body per person -->
    <tbody ng-repeat="person in persons">
      <!-- one row per home -->
      <tr ng-repeat="home in person.homes">
        <td rowspan="{{person.homes.length}}" ng-if="$index === 0">{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li>{{home.location}}</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <!-- one list per furniture -->
          <ul ng-repeat="furniture in home.furniture">
            <li>{{furniture.name}}</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

---

Alternatively, if you'd like to avoid using multiple table bodies, you could flatten your data by one dimension. For example, create a `homes` array, and reference the original `person` in each `home`. Then, use the same logic as above, but use `home.person` to reference the person instead of a repeater.

Comment: Since there's no possibility of having more than a 3 dimensional data set, I went ahead by attaching the ng-repeat to the body and setting the row span and index as suggested and works great. However, it would be nice for angular's start-end to accomplish this without repeating tbody's.